# error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol referenced in function main

Tags: visual-c++

I'm using a library to generate multimodal optimization functions using VS2010. I include the header file of the library and tell VS where the library directory is; however, there is no *.lib file that comes with it, just source files and header files, so I can't point VS to "Additional Library Directories".

If I just include the header file and run my code it works fine. If I call any method from that library I get the LNK2019 error:

> error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl g_initialize(char *)" (?g_initialize@@YAXPEAD@Z) referenced in function main".

I looked around and everyone is saying I should link the library, but I don't have a library file to begin with. What should I do??

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

There're 2 ways if you have implementation of those header files.

1) You can add it to you project.

2) To compile library yourself, and you will get *.lib files. After this add it to you project.

Read documentation of this library how to use it.
Also you can check if there's implementation methods/functions which declared in header files.